# Extract character list values from data.frame rows and reshape data

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe, reshape

I have a variable `x` with character lists in each row:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(rep('a',2),rep('b',2),'c'), 
                  x = c('f,o','f,o,o','b,a,a,r','b,a,r','b,a'), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to reshape the data so that each row is a unique (`id`, `x`) pair such as:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(id = c(rep('a',2),rep('b',3),rep('c',2)), 
                   x = c('f','o','a','b','r','a','b'))

> dat2
id x
1  a f
2  a o
3  b a
4  b b
5  b r
6  c a
7  c b
```

I've attempted to do this by splitting the character lists and keeping only the unique list values in each row:

```
dat$x <- sapply(strsplit(dat$x, ','), sort)
dat$x <- sapply(dat$x, unique)
dat <- unique(dat)

> dat
id       x
1  a    f, o
3  b a, b, r
5  c    a, b
```

However, I'm not sure how to proceed with converting the row lists into individual row entries.

How would I accomplish this? *Or* is there a more efficient way of converting a list of strings to reshape the data as described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tidytext::unnest_tokens`:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  unnest_tokens(x1, x) %>% 
  distinct()

  id x1
1  a  f
2  a  o
3  b  b
4  b  a
5  b  r
6  c  b
7  c  a
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly - thank you! Bonus points for directing me to a new, handy library.

Answer (score 2):

A base R method with two lines is

```
#get list of X potential vars
x <- strsplit(dat$x, ",")
# construct full data.frame, then use unique to return desired rows
unique(data.frame(id=rep(dat$id, lengths(x)), x=unlist(x)))
```

This returns

```
   id x
1   a f
2   a o
6   b b
7   b a
9   b r
13  c b
14  c a
```

If you don't want to write out the variable names yourself, you can use `setNames`.

```
setNames(unique(data.frame(rep(dat$id, lengths(x)), unlist(x))), names(dat))
```

Comment: This also worked very well! I'll add that you can then merge this with a larger data set with `data.table` option: `data.table(dat, key = "id")[data.table(dat_, key = "id"), allow.cartesian = T]`

Answer (score 2):

We could use `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  separate_rows(x) %>%
  distinct()
#  id x
#1  a f
#2  a o
#3  b b
#4  b a
#5  b r
#6  c b
#7  c a
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be achieved using `splitstackshape::cSplit` to split `x` column into mulltiple columns. Then `gather` and filter will help to achieve desired output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

dat %>% cSplit("x", sep=",") %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  select(-key) %>% unique()


#     id value
# 1   a     f
# 3   b     b
# 5   c     b
# 6   a     o
# 8   b     a
# 10  c     a
# 13  b     r
```

Answer (score 1):

Base solution:

```
temp <- do.call(rbind, apply( dat, 1, 
     function(z){ data.frame(
                    id=z[1], 
                    x = scan(text=z['x'], what="",sep=","),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)} ) )
Read 2 items
Read 3 items
Read 4 items
Read 3 items
Read 2 items
Warning messages:
1: In data.frame(id = z[1], x = scan(text = z["x"], what = "", sep = ",")) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
2: In data.frame(id = z[1], x = scan(text = z["x"], what = "", sep = ",")) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
3: In data.frame(id = z[1], x = scan(text = z["x"], what = "", sep = ",")) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
4: In data.frame(id = z[1], x = scan(text = z["x"], what = "", sep = ",")) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
5: In data.frame(id = z[1], x = scan(text = z["x"], what = "", sep = ",")) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

 temp[!duplicated(temp),]
 #------
   id x
1   a f
2   a o
6   b b
7   b a
9   b r
13  c b
14  c a
```

To get rid of all the messages and warnings:

```
 temp <- do.call(rbind, apply( dat, 1, 
     function(z){ suppressWarnings(data.frame(id=z[1], 
         x = scan(text=z['x'], what="",sep=",", quiet=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                )} ) )
 temp[!duplicated(temp),]
```